# Когда я использую этот код появляются какие-то запросы призраки

Tags: php

После запуска через некоторое время появляются такие логи:
`Request from  to []`  почему это происходит?

```php
<?php

if(!file_exists("config.php")){makeconf();}else{require("config.php");}

$param = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($param, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $tlscert);
stream_context_set_option($param, 'ssl', 'local_pk', $tlskey);
$sock = stream_socket_server("tls://$addr:$port",$en,$es,STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,$param);

while (1==1)
{
$s = @stream_socket_accept($sock);
$remoteaddr = @stream_socket_get_name($s,true);

$inp = @fread($s,4096);

$headers = explode("\r\n",$inp);

$method = explode(" ",$headers[0])[0];
$dest = explode(" ",$headers[0])[1];
$hhost = explode(" ",$headers[1])[1];

echo "Request from $remoteaddr to [$dest] \n";

if($log)
{
  $logp=fopen($logf,"a");
  fwrite($logp,"Request from $remoteaddr to [$dest] \n");
  fclose($logp);
}

if($hhost == $vhost){
if($method == "GET"){

if($dest == '/'){$dest = $index;}

if(file_exists("$root$dest"))
{
 foreach(file($root.$dest) as $out){}
 write(200,$out,'OK');
}else{
  if($http404 != 'false'){
    foreach(file($http404) as $out){}
    write(404,$out,'Not Found');
  }else{write(404,"<title>HTTP 404|Not Found</title><center>$dest Not Found</center>",'Not Found');}
}
}else{
  if($http500 != 'false'){
    foreach(file($http500) as $out){}
    write(500,$out,'Internal Server Error');
  }else{write(500,"<title>HTTP 500|Internal Server Error</title><center>Unsupported Method $method</center>",'Internal Server Error');}
}
}else{
  if($http403 != 'false'){
    foreach(file($http403) as $out){}
    write(403,$out,'Forbidden');
  }else{write(403,"<title>HTTP 403|Forbidden</title><center>403 Forbidden</center>",'Forbidden');}
}

@fwrite($s,$response);
@fclose($s);
}


function write($code,$body,$desc)
{
  global $response;
  $response = "HTTP/1.1 $code $desc\r\n";
  $response .= "Server: SWS\r\n";
  $response .= "Date: ".exec('date')."\r\n";
  $response .= "Status: $code\r\n";
  $response .= "Content-lenght: ".strlen($body)."\r\n";
  $response .= "Pragma: no-cache\r\n";
  $response .= "Content-type: text/html charset=utf-8\r\n";
  $response .= "x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n";
  $response .= "X-Powered-by: SWS\r\n\r\n";
  $response .= "$body\r\n\r\n";

}

function makeconf(){
  $cf = '<?php'."\n";
  $cf .= '$addr = "0.0.0.0";'."\n";
  $cf .= '$port = 443;'."\n";
  $cf .= '$vhost = "example.com";'."\n\n";
  $cf .= '$http404 = "false";'."\n";
  $cf .= '$http500 = "false";'."\n";
  $cf .= '$http403 = "false";'."\n\n";
  $cf .= '$root = "/var/www";'."\n";
  $cf .= '$index = "/index.html";'."\n\n";
  $cf .= '$tlscert = "/ssl/cert.pem";'."\n";
  $cf .= '$tlskey = "/ssl/key.pem";'."\n\n";
  $cf .= '$log = false;'."\n";
  $cf .= '$logf = "access.log";'."\n";
  $cf .= '?>'."\n";

  $conf=fopen('config.php',"w");
  fwrite($conf,$cf);
  fclose($conf);
  die("reload \n");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в коде часть функций по работе с сокетами не выдают ошибок, поскольку впереди имени функции стоит @ - например, @stream_socket_accept . Получается что если случится ошибка и будет возвращен неверный (скорее всего пустой) результат, вы об этом не узнаете. Вот оттуда и появляются

```
Request from  to [] 
fwrite($logp,"Request from $remoteaddr to [$dest] \n");
```

в $remoteaddr и $dest пустота.

Можно проверять значение $remoteaddr на пустоту и пропускать обработку таких значений.

```
$remoteaddr = @stream_socket_get_name($s,true);
if (empty($remoteaddr)) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Я знаю, я поставил `@` во время написания для тестирования. **Мой вопрос заключается в том откуда появляется пустой $remoteaddr.**  И вообще мне кажется что это TLS handshak'и

Comment: я убрал `@` и теперь:                                                                      `PHP Warning:  stream_socket_accept() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/s.php on line 12
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_get_name() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/s.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/s.php on line 15
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/s.php on line 20
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/s.php on line 21
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/s.php on line 21`

Comment: Это счастье, когда видны ошибки. Теперь можно понять что идет не так. Надо и с stream_socket_server снять @ - возможно поможет.

Comment: последняя ошибка которую я скинул была уже без @ на stream_socket_server